# Is there a way to get dd result after it's done using System.Diagnostics.Process and CMD?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dd

I'm trying to copy a source to multiple hard drives in C#. I need the process to be async so multiple units can be burnt at the same time. I do have a tool for windows which allows me to use `dd` in windows CMD.

***System.Diagnostics.Process*** is how I apply `dd` command in windows CMD.

Everything works fine but the issue is after `dd` completes copying, it does not spit out the confirmation: `x byte record in, x byte record out`, etc.
This works if I just use `dd` command manually in a windows CMD. But apparently my process gets closed before it receives final data.

```cs
private string CMD(string arg)
{
      output = "";
      System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
      System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
      startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
      startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

      startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
      startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
      startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
      startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\";
      startInfo.Arguments = arg;
      process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    
      process.Start();
      process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((s, e) =>
      {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
        {

            Invoke(new Action(() => txtMain.AppendText(e.Data.ToString() + Environment.NewLine)));

        }
        
    });
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
 
    return output;
     
}

private void ProgrameMMC()
{
 CMD("/C dd if=/cygdrive/c/masterquadimage_4GB.bin of=/dev/sdb bs=1M");
 CMD("/C dd if=/cygdrive/c/masterquadimage_4GB.bin of=/dev/sdc bs=1M");
}
```

I even tried using pv:

```cs
CMD("/C dd if=/cygdrive/c/masterquadimage.bin | pv | dd of=/dev/sdb bs=1M");
```

I still could not capture the result.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why does your `CMD()` method even have an `output` variable and a `string` return type? You never modify `output` and none of the code you posted looks at the return value anyway. As far as the general question goes, it seems _likely_ that the problem is simply that you don't wait for the process to exit, nor do you retain the `process` reference, so most likely the object is discarded before you get the last lines of output you expected. But without a [mcve] that reproduces your problem, it's not possible to provide an actual answer.

Comment: @PeterDuniho This is just part of a bigger code. Disregard the 'output' variable. You are right about waiting but how can I wait if I want the whole process to be async. The `process.start()` itself is async. The source size is larg(about 4GB).

Comment: _"how can I wait if I want the whole process to be async"_ -- there are already lots of questions with answers on Stack Overflow that address that. Not that that's the question you asked here. _"The source size is larg(about 4GB)"_ -- you misunderstand what a [mcve] is. Please read that page.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that the final message/data should be captured with error data and not standard output. All I needed to do was make a handler for `process.ErrorDataReceived`.